# re-export without the extra file?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I like to 're-export' modules in js like:

```
// combined.js
export * as A from "./a-module";

// a-module.js
export function hello1(){...}
export function hello2(){...}
```

So, I can call the functions like `A.hello1()` or `A.hello2()`. However, I would like to do this without the extra `combined.js` file. I also don't want to use default or `*` imports. Yes I can do:

`import * as A from "./a-module"` or `import A from "./a-module"` (if I do a default export instead), but I like my named exports.

Comment: `import * as A from "./a-module"` is exactly what you should be writing. What's wrong with that?

Comment: On one hand you don't want an extra file but you want to re-export some values? Where do you want re-export them from? I'm a bit confused. `import * as A from "./a-module"` seems to do exactly what you want?

Comment: Where do you want to import these? And what is the import syntax that you desire?

Comment: I see a lot of confusion so my question is not that clean. What I'm trying to do is to export a named module so almost like a namespace. I want to namespace a module so I can export it while being named. If that makes sense. So something like: `export namespace A { ...functions here... }`

Comment: A module is already kind of a namespace. Why does `import * as A from "./a-module"` not work for your purposes?

Comment: I don't like the fact that `A` is not named. And what I mean by that is that I can import this module in different files naming them all differently.

Comment: Personally I see this as an advantage but everyone has different preferences. You could add `export const A = {hello1, hello2};` do your file then callers can use `import {A} from "...";`. But note that callers can still rename the import via `import {A as B} from '...'`. But I would really verify again why this bothers you. If this module is to be consumed by others then you should give them the freedom to name the import however you want. If it's only used by yourself, well you have control over your actions :)